# Find the range of $k$ so that $\prod \limits_\text{cyc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}-k\right)\ge \left(\sqrt{\frac12}-k\right)^3$

Tags: inequality

Here $a,b,c>0$

> **A similar inequality i got is this one**
>
> For $a,b,c>0,1\le k\le3,$ prove that $$\left(
>  \sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}-k\right) \left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}}-k\right)
>  \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}-k\right) \ge{\left(
>  \sqrt{\frac12}-k\right) ^3}$$

How can i find this range through the inequality. I thought the same approach to this one will lead me to the range but no. And also i don't know if the given range is a subset of actual range.

Help me out.